# Replace foreach with java8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, generic-collections

How can I convert this code as per java8 having an inner list inside a parent list and do filtering?

```
for(A aobj: branchList) {
    for(C cobj : aobj.getCList()) {
        if(!enteredBranchId.equals(cobj.getId())
            myList.add(aobj.getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, where did you run into a problem with Java streams? Do you know what a `flatMap` operation is? What a `collect` is supposed to do and what collectors are available? Did you try to use any and failed?

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/3-reasons-why-you-shouldnt-replace-your-for-loops

Comment: Vague title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: @RealSkeptic - I did use a couple of functions but could not make the one needed. Any help with the code is helpful!

Answer (score 2):

```
myList = branchList.stream()
           .map(b -> b.getSubBranches())  
           .flatMap(Collection::stream)
           .filter(sb -> !enteredBranchId.equals(sb.getBranchId()))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `getSubBranches()` in your `flatMap`?

Comment: won't the getBranchId() will throw a compile-time exception? and so does the Collection::stream as the non-static method context error?

Comment: @JacobG. true, for the `flatMap` to work the `branchList` is got tot be a `Collection<Collection<T>>`, besides that, even if it would work, the answer does not even deal with class `C` in the question. Downvoting for this reason.

Comment: @JacobG. true, I forgot that step. @Naman This answer was done on the first version of the question. If you notice multiple edits were done, and the class `C` was added later on.

Comment: `map(b -> b.getSubBranches())  
           .flatMap(Collection::stream)` can be converted to  `flatMap(b -> b.getSubBranches().stream())`